# Different Segues from Different UITableViewCells?

Tags: uitableview, segue, uistoryboard

This appears to be a storyboard editor issue because it's easy to do in code.

I have a UITableView with two different prototype cells.  They have reuse identifiers, different accessories.  I want selecting one type to trigger a segue to another view controller, and selecting the other to go to a different view controller.  But as soon as I create the second segue in the storyboard editor, the first one is replaced.  Even if I have named it.

It seems this should be a common enough scenario, I should be able to have multiple segues, and differentiate them in prepareForSegue.

I need to note, this is easy to do in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the view controller's table view delegate, but there I have to explicitly load the template from the storyboard (unless I use a generic and don't need a nib).

Has anyone been able to get this to work in the storyboard editor?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of to do this with how things currently work is by using two different types of prototype cells. (two separate classes) and assigning each different segue to each different subclassed prototype cell.